# Excel - Finding work days in a month between two dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have successfully managed to calculate the number of days in a specific month between two dates. However I need to calculate those days as work days within the formula. For example.

|  ------------- A  --------------------  B   ---------------  C
| 1 ------- 11/12/2014 ----- 17/03/2015 ----- 01/03/2015
| 2

A - Being the start date
B - Being the End date
C - Being the month to check the number of days range A1:B1 falls within. (In this case March)

```
=MAX(0,MIN(EOMONTH(C$1,0),$B1)-MAX(C$1,$A1)+1)
```

This should produce 17, which is the number of regular days. How can I produce the number of working days, and incorporate

```
=NETWORKDAYS()
```

Ultimately the answer should be 12.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
=NETWORKDAYS(MAX(A1,C1),MIN(B1,EOMONTH(C1,0)))
```

It might be wise to expand it with some error checking like so:

```
=IF(NETWORKDAYS(MAX(A1,C1),MIN(B1,EOMONTH(C1,0)))<0,0,NETWORKDAYS(MAX(A1,C1),MIN(B1,EOMONTH(C1,0))))
```

Comment: To ensure no negative values you can just use MAX like the original formula, i.e. `=MAX(0,NETWORKDAYS(MAX($A1,C$1),MIN($B1,EOMONTH(C$1,0))))`